# Error when installing Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 via VirtualBox

Tags: linux, rhel, virtualbox

Getting this error when installing linux from iso using VirtualBox 6.1. I have tried Linux 8.6 and 8.2 and both are giving same error. I also tried a workaround of disabling "Connect to redhat insight". What is solution for this ? I am really tired trying to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look at the messate, it says that the packages in the local repository. IE, the ISO, have an invalid checksum. Have you tried downloading the ISO again and testing it for errors before you begin?

Comment: @NasirRiley Downloaded both 8.6 and 8.2 twice so far, same error.

Comment: Did you test them for errors before installation?

Comment: @NasirRiley Getting error when checking media. Updated question with screenshot

Comment: Then you'll need to download it from a different source.

Comment: @NasirRiley oh ok where can I install from ? Appreciate your help

Comment: That is something that you can find via Google. A good place to start would be the Red Hat customer portal.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the source from where you download the images is unreliable. The best site to download RHEL is [RedHat web site](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download). You may need to create free development account for this.

Comment: Yes thats where I downloaded it from. And tried multiple times as well.

Comment: @PitDigger, did you compare downloaded file with provided hash?

Answer (score -1):

If the host OS is Windows, you may want to disable the Hyper-V supervisor:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v

Docker (demanding Hyper-V) doesn't play well with VirtualBox or VMWare.

Comment: If the Hyper-V is activated I have my doubts OP will be able to start/install Virtualbox

Comment: @RomeoNinov It seems as you haven't even read the question ...which by the way doesn't state which host OS, nor the eventual order of installing conflicting hypervisors; this "Containers" component may also conflict. Your cognitive bias isn't helpful at all.